# Bluetooth unsuported on my real device

Tags: ios, github, bluetooth

I use the repo BlueCap to manage bluetooth connections. But when I run the example (center) to scan around, it shows

```
Unsuported - 'Unavailable'
```

My real device is an Ipad 2 and I also tested it on an Iphone 6

Comment: It doesn't work at all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this line to the `plist` file.

[image]